# Why is "BroadcastChannel" class undefined in tests?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, broadcast

I use the standardized Broadcast Channel API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API) for messaging between multiple tabs when a session timeout occurs in our react app.

On all tested browsers, this works just fine. But when I run our jest tests I get the following error message: "ReferenceError: BroadcastChannel is not defined"

I define a BroadcastChannel instance outside of our hook like this:

```
const sessionTimeoutChannel = new BroadcastChannel("session_timeout_channel");

export default function useSessionTimeout() {...}
```

Has anybody any idea why the tests seemingly dont know of the BroadcastChannel API? Or knows of a workaround so that the tests run again?

Comment: Any movement on this one?

Answer (score 0):

No experience here, but it could be that your tests are run in nodejs... so not actually having browser support. I found this on npm, maybe it needs to be added to your tests project? https://www.npmjs.com/package/broadcast-channel

Comment: As far as the documentation goes, NodeJS should support BroadcastChannel. The module you suggest seems to be a different API than the standard.

Comment: OK. I could only try to help with troubleshooting, I don't have any practical experience.  Are you using nodeJS v15.4+? It also mentions that these are in the worker threads module, https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html#class-broadcastchannel-extends-eventtarget maybe it needs to be imported? I've also found this https://dev.to/akinncar/how-to-solve-broadcastchannel-is-not-defined-4cjh#:~:text=Jest%20can't%20find%20BroadcastChannel,and%20help%20old%20browsers%20support).&text=Then%2C%20import%20BroadcastChannel%20where%20you,code%20should%20be%20the%20same).

Comment: Thank you for your contribution! We had already tried the worker-thread approach, but that has not helped either. Also, the blog you suggested uses the same non-standard API you mentioned in your answer. It seems, we have to find a way to mock around this problem...

Comment: Hi @melix, did you manage to find a solution for this? I have the same exact issue.

Comment: Hey, sadly we found no solution other than to mock around that issue with a substitute class.

Comment: [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75809272) solved this issue for me. It might be what @melix meant