# ReferenceError: BroadcastChannel is not defined using jest testing libray

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm getting error while runing the jest test case using react-testing library

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have resolved it in following way

step 1: I have created config/jest.setup.js in root folder and pasted below code in jest.setup.js file

```
function channelMock() {}
channelMock.prototype.onmessage = function () {}
channelMock.prototype.postMessage = function (data) {
    this.onmessage({ data })
}
global.BroadcastChannel = channelMock
```

step 2: In package.js file we need to add this file path in following way

```
"jest": {
        "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
            "./config/jest.setup.js"
        ]
    },
```

step 3: then you can run the test case using

```
npm run test
```

Issue resolved

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, the [`BroadcastChannel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BroadcastChannel#browser_compatibility) is also available through the Node native [`"worker_threads"`](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) module.

All you need to do is run this in/before your test:

```js
self.BroadcastChannel = require('worker_threads').BroadcastChannel;
```